# How to move to previous fragment on back button click

Tags: android

In my app there is navigation drawer.
I opened the same fragment from navigation drawer and from  other fragment in my app.
there is back button on my same fragment .
I want
when i click on the back button 
if the same fragment is opened from navigation drawer it goes back to another fragment A.
if the same fragment is opened from other fragment it goes back to B fragment.

Comment: Write same thing on google search engine. And you will get so many answer for this.

Comment: Your title is very clear,but the content in  your question is very confusing..

Comment: getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

Comment: # Mrinmoy getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you have navigation back button then use

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

> Override onBackPress();

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 1) {
                finish();// finish activity if you are at home screen
                return;
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();//will pop previous fragment
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```